# Subtracting two different data frames with different shapes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Input sample data frames (Multiple columns and rows, only a sample is pasted here) like below :

[image]

I want the output to be:

[image]

Comment: 1) Also, please provide a reproducible example, it'll make it more likely you get help. 2) What have you tried already?

Comment: Hi Nani.  I read your question, I have provided the answer below.  If you encounter a warning, can ignore the warning. Please see if this is what you wanted.    If this is what you want, kindly click check to accept the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('ProjectID.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet4')
df2 = pd.read_excel('ProjectID.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet5')
df3 = df1[['Index1','Index2']]
```

Output:

```
    Index1  Index2  100a    101b    102a
0   100 a   50  60  70
1   100 b   70  80  90
2   101 a   60  70  80
3   101 b   80  80  1
4   101 b   70  70  70
5   102 a   100 100 90
6   102 b   200 200 80
Index1  Index2  col1
0   100 a   50
1   100 b   30
2   101 a   60
3   101 b   50
4   101 b   100
5   102 a   50
6   102 b   20
Index1  Index2
0   100 a
1   100 b
2   101 a
3   101 b
4   101 b
5   102 a
6   102 b
```

Code:

```
df3['100a'] = df1['100a'] - df2['col1']
df3['101b'] = df1['101b'] - df2['col1']
df3['102a'] = df1['102a'] - df2['col1']
df3
```

Note: can ignore the warning

Output:

```
    Index1  Index2  100a    101b    102a
0   100     a       0       10      20
1   100     b       40      50      60
2   101     a       0       10      20
3   101     b       30      30      -49
4   101     b      -30      -30     -30
5   102     a       50      50      40
6   102     b       180     180     60
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply and your precious time. I have many columns like about 100 columns like that. So hardcoding each column takes a lot of time. Is there any other alternative to this, please?

Comment: Could you give more info about the columns ?  eg is there any pattern to the columns, in terms of naming ?  or positoins ?  Could you provide a sample of the columns eg, df.columns ?  If there is a pattern to the columns, then its possible to program it.  If not, then you have to identify the columns manually.  eg if it's in df1, for columns position (2,3,4), (5,6,7), (8,9,10),.... and df2 is just (2), ((3),... then it's possible to play with the offset and code an algo.

Comment: If there is no pattern, then you may have to create a list of column eg [(100a,101b,102a),(col1), (xxx.yyy.zzz),(aaa)......] and loop through it.